# Gulp4 watch: lint modified file only (series)

Tags: javascript, gulp-watch, stylelint, gulp-4

I want my **gulp4** [`watch`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/) task to [`lint`](https://github.com/olegskl/gulp-stylelint) the currently modified file only, so the console output is succinct for debugging purposes.

A [`series`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series/) should be executed:

- lintCSS
- compileCSS
- reload

*Working* - Linting *all* css files:

```
function watchCSS() {
    return watch(config.path.scss,                  
        series(
            lintCSSAll,
            compileCSS,
            reload      
        )
    )
};
```

*Non-working* - I can successfully get and lint the *currently modified file*, but the series never executes:

```
function watchCSS() {
    return watch(config.path.scss).on('all', function(stats, path) {
            console.log('Modified: ' + path);
            lintCSS(path);
            series(
                compileCSS,
                reload
            )
       });
};
```

I do not receive any error messages from the failed series.

Is there a better way to chain the lint -> compileCSS -> reload processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above non-working example could not have worked, because it relies [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) on which does not support `series`.

From the [docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/watching-files#using-the-watcher-instance):

> The returned chokidar instance doesn't have queueing, delay, or async
> completion features.

**Solution**

Use [gulp-cached](https://github.com/gulp-community/gulp-cached) instead:

```
const cache = require('gulp-cached');

function lintCSS() {
    return src(config.path.scss)
        .pipe(cache('lint-css'))
        .pipe(stylelint());
};
```